# Covert UTF-16 Character Code (number) to String in Java

Tags: java, utf-16

How do I simply convert a UTF-16 character to String?

something Like

```
String str = TheMagicalFunction(0x25E6);
```

Comment: That's a number, not a character.

Comment: @MattBall if we want to be pedantic, it's actually a sequence of 6 characters.

Comment: Two possibilities - either the question asker was too lazy to write "the character represented by the single code point 0x25E6" (which is fair enough) or the question asker doesn't know the difference between a character and a code point (in which case they should probably ask).

Comment: @MattBall Well, `char c = 0x25E6;` compiles fine and will produce the same byte code as `char c = '◦';`.

Comment: Just to clarify: the asker was lazy to include the details ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Character.toString(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString-char-):

```
String str = Character.toString((char) 0x25E6);
```

You can omit the cast when first storing the character in a variable …

```
char whiteBullet = 0x25E6;
String whiteBulletString = Character.toString(whiteBullet);
```

… or when using a [Unicode escape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) which in this case is easy since the character belongs to the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP):

```
String str = Character.toString('\u25E6');
```

The method [`String.valueOf(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-char-) is equivalent and/but has multiple overloads. Beware of this:

```
String str = String.valueOf(0x25E6); // "9702" (decimal value)
String str2 = String.valueOf((char) 0x25E6); // "◦"
String str3 = String.valueOf('\u25E6'); // "◦"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- If the character is an integer, cast it to `char`.
- Put it in a 1-element `char[]`.
- Pass it the the `String` constructor.

So,

```
String str = new String(new char[] {(char) 0x25E6});
```